# strategy.close() does not close position

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a strategy, where I set the alert message and that message appears in the list of alerts while the position is not closed in the list of trades. See screenshot. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJkHJ.jpg)

The line which should close the position:

```
strategy.close("position #" + str.tostring(pyramidClosed), alert_message="TRADE" + alertMessage)
```

The `pyramidClosed` is an incremental variable to close the positions in chronological order.

The alert message:

```
alertMessage := "#5 - Decrease buying position" + "\n"
     + "(+)Diff.: " + str.tostring(diff) + "%\n"
     + "Sold " + str.tostring(TradeBaseSize) + " " + syminfo.basecurrency + " for " + str.tostring(TradeCurrencySize) + " " + syminfo.currency + "\n"
     + "Last: " + str.tostring(last_price) + "\n"
     + "Actual: " + str.tostring(actual_price) + "\n"
     + "Time5: " + str.tostring(timediff) + "\n"
     + "DCA: " + str.tostring(DCA) + "\n"
     + "Pos.: " + "position #" + str.tostring(pyramidClosed) + "\n" + "\n"
```

So, in theorem position#-4 should be closed.

What I really don't understand that the first three position are closed correctly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is that possible that the list of trades "refreshes" the list with some extreme delay? Like an hour?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the full code.

Comment: What I find really strange, that everything seems to work as it should until the browser's window is refreshed, or if I open tradingview in another window, or if I close the browser and open it again. Then the alerts are completely go random. If I delete the alert and add it again then it works until the above events.

Comment: I am 99% sure that your issue comes from all those `varip` variables you use. It fits perfectly to the scenario you described. Their values will be updated with each tick, so your script will work fine as long as you don't refresh. But then once you refresh, their values will be reset hence it will break your history.

Comment: Do you really need those variables to be `varip`?

Comment: Keep in mind that the one strategy instance are working in "alert mode" and the second strategy instance are working on "your chart" - they aren't synced at all.

Comment: vitruvius - I used varip because my chart is on 1-day while the calculations should update the variables on each tick while remembering the previous value, like in case of DCA or last price action, or do I misunderstand the usage of varip?

Comment: Andrey D - What I want is to use the alerts for trading with AutoView plugin, while keeping track on the chart, and if needed reset or recalibrate the strategy. Are you saying, that is not possible with this method I want to do?